# Chrome's Device toolbar dimensions seem off

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome to build a web-based user interface for an application on the Raspberry Pi touch screen. That screen is 800x480 pixels, so I have clear dimensions of how large everything should be.

In Chrome, you can easily scale your page to have those dimensions, using the "Device toolbar" in the development tools (F12).

However, it looks like something is going wrong there, see the image below:
[image]

The screen is 800x480, but the selected `nav` tag is 980 pixels wide and still fits inside the screen! (And indeed when running the UI on the Raspberry Pi screen, it was wrong)

Am I using the tool incorrectly, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was caused by the fact that my website was not configured correctly for mobile.

To fix it, I had to add to the head element the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```